# How to get transfers and holders in one contract by etherscan.io

Tags: etherscan

My dear friends:
I am a beginner in ethereum development,And i have a problem and I hope I can get help.
I signed up with EtherScan and got a free key and some data from the API. Their API experience was very good.

My question:

Is there an EtherScan API Can let me through a smart contracts (0 x3103df8f05c4d8af16fd22ae63e406b97fec6938) under the page (https://etherscan.io/token/0x3103df8f05c4d8af16fd22ae63e406b97fec6938) get Transfers and holders data.

I know I can get it by downloading CSV, but I want to get it by calling the API in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x3103dF8F05c4D8aF16fD22AE63E406b97FeC6938&startblock=0&sort=desc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken) is to get the token's transfers list. [Source](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-erc20-token-transfer-events-by-address)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is caused by my not reading the API clearly. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: No problem, we are here to help out each other.